# Hashtag valid variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, symbols

I have looked up valid variable names in javascript, and apparently the hashtag is not included in the list of characters. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: You mean the hash character (aka pound, aka number). 'Hashtag' isn't a character - its a label or type of metadata. /pedant

Answer (score 19):

With '#' being the prefix for private variables, there will also be restrictions with this in the future.

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields

Answer (score 2):

You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types)

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean #, it's invalid to use as part of a variable name because it's a punctuation mark.  You wouldn't use a ',' either.  It's not a mixed meaning thing like a '.' which is obviously because child properties/methods would be accessed using dot-notation, or a '>' which is obviously the operator for greater than, but it's just not something you should be using as a variable in any language (my opinion).  Just makes things more readable to keep to Alpha/Alphanumeric and, at most, '_' or '-'.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields